# What does "rue" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Unlike the name of the San Antonio street their now-ex point guard once called home, the Spurs today will choose not to **rue** Parker. Instead, the team will celebrate him and his hallowed place amid the greatest era of the franchise’s history. ([source](https://www.expressnews.com/spurs-nation/article/Parker-stunner-Iconic-Spurs-point-guard-headed-13055154.php))

As far as dictionaries and my knowledge of the word go, "to rue" means "to regret", but it doesn't make sense here. What does the word mean in this context? How do you rue someone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the usage is odd. We don't typically rue someone. It appears to me the author is trying to say that Spurs will choose to not regret letting Parker decide to leave.

However, earlier the author wrote (my emphasis):

> Or how important Parker has been to the city of San Antonio. He once built a house on a street on the city’s northwest side named in his honor: **Rue Parker**.

*Rue* means street in French and it's sometimes used in street names, similar to Drive, Road, or Boulevard. It appears the misuse was intentional for the sake of word play.

Answer (score 0):

According to the article

> "He once built a house on a street on the city’s northwest side named in his honor: **Rue Parker**."

***Rue*** is french for street.

So the writer may be saying they will not be doing that for *him*.